# How to cancel a ongoing asynctask and start it again in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask which is called whenever the camera is moved in Google Maps because i want to load new data from web services against the co-ordinates of center point of the map. Now everything is working fine but the thing is that whenever user move the map very fast, the tasks start queuing up. In the result when user stop moving map, the task in queues keep loading the old data until the task which is in the last, come with actual data.

My AsyncTask Class:

```
private class GetOffersLocations extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String[]... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        [web api called in here and load the data against the center point (latlng)]
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCancelled();
        this.cancel(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (result) {
        [drawing pins on map here]
        }
    }
}
```

And here in a function i called this AsyncTask on camera move of the map:

```
private void showMarkers(String lat, String lng, String radius, int position) {
    String[] latLng = { lat, lng, radius, String.valueOf(position) };
    new getOffersLocations().execute(latLng);
}
```

Now this function is called in OnCameraChangeListener and when ever user move the camera this asynctask is called.
So, i think i properly made my question and if not please correct me.
Waiting for help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't stop and start again an AsyncTask, but you can cancel it execution by calling

```
myGetOffersLocations.cancel(true);
```

This will interrupt the execution, however, you will need to create a new AsyncTask object to be able to run it again, so you can do this:

```
myGetOffersLocations.cancel(true);
myGetOffersLocations = new GetOffersLocations();
```

And then, run it again.

NOTE: Make sure you create an object reference to the AsyncTask, instead of executing it directly as you're doing on your method.

Replace this:

```
new getOffersLocations().execute(latLng);
```

With this:

```
getOffersLocations myOffers = new getOffersLocations();
myOffers.execute(latLng);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply .. but where should i can the `cancel(true)` because my function  `showMarkers()` only called when the map is moved?

Comment: You should call the cancel method from the piece of code where you want the AsyncTask to be stoped, i mean, if you want it to stop when you click a button, you should add it in to the OnClick method from the button.

Comment: that is the think, i cant let user to stop the task, i have to stop it programmatically, normally my code runs perfect, im talking about the case where user is moving the map very fast letting the old tasks not to complete, thus a queue of tasks start creating

Comment: In your case, you need to capture the map movement event, i don't know which events can be used from the map because i have not work with maps yet, but im pretty sure it have a map scroll or something like that, check which events you can capture from your map object, and cancel the task on it.

Answer (score 3):

in your `doInBackground` make sure you are doing something like this

```
while(!isCancelled()){
   // Do I/O work
}
```

and your for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100 && !isCancelled(); ++i){
   // Do something
}
```

You can cancel it like this

```
myGetOffersLocations.cancel(true);
myGetOffersLocations = new GetOffersLocations();
```

Cancelling a task (quoted from [AsyncTask | Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)))

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean).
>   Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to
>   return true.
>
> After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of
>   onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[])
>   returns.
>
> To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should
>   always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from
>   doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

Comment: But if interrupt is sent when compiler is already in the while loop then its too late, hence my statement that cancel(true) won't always cancel the task..

Comment: It will not always yes, you have to make sure you implement your task in a such way that it is... take for example reading a file line by line... your while loop would by something like this while (!isCanceled() && (line = br.readLine()) != null) so in the worst case, it would read another line and then cancel itself instead of reading until end

Comment: Yes if reading/writing its simple for if there is just one network call then its a boolean state - call gone or we cancelled it in time

Comment: I know asynctask is not perfect for this also for several other reasons... that's why implemented my own thread pool and started using loaders instead.

Comment: thanks for your reply but why would i need a loop? :S

Comment: That pretty much depends on what you are doing in your webapi. If for example you are downloading a file, you should be reading it in a buffer and in each iteration check if the task is canceled and stop downloading. The same would go for reading an XML input stream or something.

Comment: @BojanKseneman im not downloading files, the webapi only return me the nearest locations from the latlng i provide it. So and it reply me very fast, and it works perfect normaly. Im talking about the case when user move the map very fast and `OnCameraChangeListiner` is called everytime

Comment: Then just cancel it and you are done. No need to check anything. Tough using a Loader, you just call restart on it and it will discard current progress and restart. It might be better in your case.

Comment: i have tried it but its not canceling the task, and a queue still create

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of the AsyncTask class and call execute(..) on it:

```
GetOffersLocation mGOL =  new getOffersLocations();
mGol.execute(latLng)
```

When you need to cancel the task call:

```
mGol.cancel(true);
```

This will send a signal to ongoing task and try to cancel it.

I say try, because AsyncTasks do not terminate everytime necessarily.

Comment: thanks for your reply but can you please tell me where should i call the `cancel(true)` as my function `showmarkers()` only called when map is moved.